# Launch fancyBox from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Im stuck with a little problem with fancyBox v2.

I want to launch fancyBox on button click. Once clicked, it will load all the images from the list (from the src attribute of the ).

I have created this jsfiddle to show what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/fPFZg/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $.fancybox(); 
    });
});
```

Can anybody see how this would be possible?

Comment: you could initialize fancybox on the document ready, then manually fire a click event on one of the images

Answer (score 8):

I had the same question and found the following to be a simpler method:

#### HTML

```
    <button class="fancybox" value="Open Fancybox">Open Fancybox</button>
    <div class="hidden" id="fancybox-popup-form">
        (your Fancybox content goes in here)
    </div>
```

#### jQuery

```
    $('.fancybox').click(function () {
        $.fancybox([
            { href : '#fancybox-popup-form' }
        ]);
    });
```

#### CSS

```
    .hidden { display: none; }
```

#### Further Reading

[Fancybox Docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) (click the "API Methods" tab, then read up on the first method, which is called "Open").

Comment: This fixed an issue for me while trying to popup a fanybox 1.x version dynamicly with javascript, as it kept flashing when I clicked it. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

you can use it like this:

```
    $.fancybox.open([
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
        title : '1st title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
        title : '2nd title'
    }    
], {
    padding : 0   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because this `$.fancybox();` doesn't tell fancybox what to open so does nothing.

What I would do, if you don't want to edit every link in your html, is:

1). add an `ID` to the `<ul>` tag so we can use that selector like

```
<ul id="images">
```

2). bind fancybox to all `<a>` anchors that are child of your element `#images` like

```
var fancyGallery = $("#images").find("a"); // we cache the selector here
fancyGallery.attr("rel","gallery").fancybox({
    type: "image"
});
```

**notice** that we are adding a `rel` attribute on the fly to all anchors so they will be part of the same gallery

3). bind a `click` event to the `button` (I would recommend you to give it an `ID` too so it won't mess with other possible *buttons* in the future) that triggers the existing fancybox script as above, so with this html

```
<button id="fancyLaunch">Launch Fancybox</button>
```

use this script

```
$('#fancyLaunch').on('click', function() {
    fancyGallery.eq(0).click(); // triggers a click
});
```

**notice** that we used the method `.eq()` to launch the gallery from the **first** item (first `index` in javascript is always 0)

Summarizing, your whole script may look like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var fancyGallery = $("#images").find("a");
    fancyGallery.attr("rel","gallery").fancybox({
        type: "image"
    });
    $('#fancyLaunch').on('click', function() {
        fancyGallery.eq(0).click(); 
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9m9PV/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your html:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="http://placekitten.com/400/400" title="" class="fancybox">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>

 <li>
    <a href="http://placekitten.com/400/400" title="" class="fancybox">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://placekitten.com/400/400" title="" class="fancybox">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="http://placekitten.com/400/400" title="" class="fancybox">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="" />
    </a>
</li>
```

Your jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $.fancybox($("a.fancybox")); 
});});
```